# How to predict y=1/x values in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

I have a data frame named `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'p': [15-x for x in range(14)]
                  , 'x': [x for x in range(14)]})

df['y'] = 1000 * (10 / df['p'])
```

`x` is only for plotting purposes.
I'm trying to predict the `y` value based on the `p` values. I am using [SVR from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR

nlm = SVR(kernel='poly').fit(df[['p']], df['y'])
df['nml'] = nlm.predict(df[['p']])
```

I have already tried all of kernels but it still doesn't work correct enough.

```
     p   x            y          nml
0   15   0   666.666667   524.669572
1   14   1   714.285714   713.042459
2   13   2   769.230769   876.338765
3   12   3   833.333333  1016.349674
```

[image: grey: p, blue: y, orange: nlm]

Do you know which sklearn model or other libraries should I use to better fit a model?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you get more focuss into that questions?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have added a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the fundamental step **"normalize the data"**

#### Fix

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p': [15-x for x in range(14)]
                  , 'x': [x for x in range(14)]})

df['y'] = 1000 * (10 / df['p'])

# Normalize the data (x - mean(x))/std(x)
s_p = np.std(df['p'])
m_p = np.mean(df['p'])

s_y = np.std(df['y'])
m_y = np.mean(df['y'])
                        
df['p_'] = (df['p'] - s_p)/m_p
df['y_'] = (df['y'] - s_y)/m_y

# Fit and make prediction
nlm = SVR(kernel='rbf').fit(df[['p_']], df['y_'])
df['nml'] = nlm.predict(df[['p_']])

# Plot
plt.plot(df['p_'], df['y_'], 'r')
plt.plot(df['p_'], df['nml'], 'g')
plt.show()

# Rescale back and plot
plt.plot(df['p_']*s_p+m_p, df['y_']*s_y+m_y, 'r')
plt.plot(df['p_']*s_p+m_p, df['nml']*s_y+m_y, 'g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Should I also normalize the data while using Linear Regression?

Comment: Yes for any ML model you should normalize the data except it is not needed for  tree based models. It does not hurt though if you normalize for tree based models also.

Answer (score 1):

As @mujjiga pointed out, scaling is important part of the process.

I would like to draw your attention on another two key points:

- model selection which determines your ability to solve a class of problem;
- new `scklearn` API which helps you to standardize solution development.

Let's start with your dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(14)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'p': 15-x})
df['y'] = 1e4/df['p']
```

Then we import  some`sklearn` API objects of interest:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, RobustScaler, FunctionTransformer
```

First we create a scaler function for target values:

```
ysc = StandardScaler()
```

Notice that we can use different [scalers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing), or build a [custom transformation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html).

```
# Scaler robust against outliers:
ysc = RobustScaler()

# Logarithmic Transformation:
ysc = FunctionTransformer(func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp, check_inverse=True)
```

We scale target using the scaler of our choice:

```
ysc.fit(df[['y']])
df['yn'] = ysc.transform(df[['y']])
```

We also build a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline) with features standardizer and the **selected model** (we adjusted parameters to improve the fit). We fit it to your dataset using the pipeline:

```
reg = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, epsilon=1e-3))
reg.fit(df[['p']], df['yn'])
```

At this point we can predict values and transform them back to the original scale:

```
df['ynhat'] = reg.predict(df[['p']])
df['yhat'] = ysc.inverse_transform(df[['ynhat']])
```

We check the fit score:

```
reg.score(df[['p']], df['yn']) # 0.9999646718755011
```

We can also compute absolute and relative error for each point:

```
df['yaerr'] = df['yhat'] - df['y']
df['yrerr'] = df['yaerr']/df['y']
```

Final result is:

```
     x   p            y        yn     ynhat         yhat      yaerr     yrerr
0    0  15   666.666667 -0.834823 -0.833633   668.077018   1.410352  0.002116
1    1  14   714.285714 -0.794636 -0.795247   713.562403  -0.723312 -0.001013
2    2  13   769.230769 -0.748267 -0.749627   767.619013  -1.611756 -0.002095
3    3  12   833.333333 -0.694169 -0.693498   834.128425   0.795091  0.000954
4    4  11   909.090909 -0.630235 -0.629048   910.497550   1.406641  0.001547
5    5  10  1000.000000 -0.553514 -0.555029   998.204445  -1.795555 -0.001796
6    6   9  1111.111111 -0.459744 -0.460002  1110.805275  -0.305836 -0.000275
7    7   8  1250.000000 -0.342532 -0.341099  1251.697707   1.697707  0.001358
8    8   7  1428.571429 -0.191830 -0.193295  1426.835676  -1.735753 -0.001215
9    9   6  1666.666667  0.009105  0.010458  1668.269984   1.603317  0.000962
10  10   5  2000.000000  0.290414  0.291060  2000.764717   0.764717  0.000382
11  11   4  2500.000000  0.712379  0.690511  2474.088446 -25.911554 -0.010365
12  12   3  3333.333333  1.415652  1.416874  3334.780642   1.447309  0.000434
13  13   2  5000.000000  2.822199  2.821420  4999.076799  -0.923201 -0.000185
```

Graphically it leads to:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(df['p'], df['y'], label='$y(p)$')
axe.plot(df['p'], df['yhat'], 'o', label='$\hat{y}(p)$')
axe.set_title(r"SVR Fit for $y(x) = \frac{k}{x-a}$")
axe.set_xlabel('$p = x-a$')
axe.set_ylabel('$y, \hat{y}$')
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image: Fit Result]

### Linearization

In the example above we could not use the `poly` kernel, we had to use the `rbf` kernel instead. This is because if we aim to fit a rational function using polynomial we are better to transform our data before fitting using a `p = x/(x-b)` substitution at the first place. In this case it will merely boil down to perform a linear regression. The example below shows that it works:

Scaler and transformation can be composed into a pipeline as well. We define a pipeline that linearize and scale the problem:

```
# Rational Fraction Substitution with consecutive Standardization
ysc = make_pipeline(
          FunctionTransformer(func=lambda x: x/(x+1),
                              inverse_func=lambda x: x/(1-x),
                              check_inverse=True),
          StandardScaler()
)
```

Then we can regress the data using classical OLS:

```
reg = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LinearRegression())
reg.fit(df[['p']], df['yn'])
```

Which provides correct result:

```
reg.score(df[['p']], df['yn']) # 0.9999998722172933
```

This second solution take advantage of a known linearization and thus remove the need to parametrize the model.